# Parts involved in starting PC and making it usable

Tags: boot, bios, bootloader

Going from the most basic to most abstract what is the order of things that are used when a PC is powered on? Is the BIOS loaded first? I heard the BIOS is responsible for loading the bootloader and the firmware. Does one necessarily happen before the other? The job of the bootloader is to load the operating system, why doesn't the BIOS do this itself?

Basically what's the ranking of:

- BIOS
- Operating system
- Bootloader
- Firmware

EDIT: It's also my understanding the power supply is the first thing that turns on when the on button is pressed, and it's does some testing. Is this true that it's the first part of the computer to be turned on?

Answer (score 1):

The order is:

- BIOS or UEFI firmware

which finds and loads the

- Bootloader (from a boot device)

which finds and loads the

- Operating system

The BIOS is in either a ROM, EEPROM, or (typically) ROM-like NOR flash, and is "already there" on power up.  Nothing needs to load it on a PC.

> The job of the bootloader is to load the operating system, why doesn't the BIOS do this itself?

The PC BIOS goes all the way back to 1981, when the first PC was produced, and it was basically based on the role the BIOS played in the old 8-bit CP/M OS stack.  (DOS was very similar to CP/M in most respects, particularly the original version 1.0).  This role meant that the BIOS didn't understand filesystems, but only could read and write to a few defined devices, including disk sectors.  The BIOS was supposed to be simple so it could be ported to different hardware easily, most likely.

Additionally ROM space was very expensive in those days and filesystems were also considered part of the operating system (really to this day only a few Unix-like OSes like Linux and some BSDs really support multiple filesystems very well.)

UEFI, the successor to the BIOS, can understand filesystems (FAT32 if I'm not mistaken at the very least), and can load an operating system directly ([how to do it for Linux](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/EFI_stub_kernel)).  Despite this, the typical setup that ends up happening in most Windows systems is that the "Windows Boot Manager" is loaded by the BIOS or UEFI, which then finds and loads the OS.  Windows probably went this route to have a single common component that works on both BIOS and UEFI systems.

As far as why, in the long stretch of time between 1981 and the advent of UEFI, that no one bothered to extend the BIOS to understand filesystems, some insights are:

- No one really "owns" the PC platform, even though IBM invented it, Microsoft software has been the reason most people buy it, and Intel now makes most of the components in it (and has always made its CPU).  The first non-IBM BIOS was a clean-room reverse engineered clone of the IBM one - which then distilled into the two main companies that develop and produce BIOSes and firmware.  So, the PC firmware is sort of caught in the middle here and at the mercy of a lot of "mutilateral" cooperation/competition from diverse corporations with competing agendas.  (ACPI is one result of this.)
- Given DOS and then Windows dominance of the PC market and eventual influence over OEMs, that meant it ended up that the BIOS had to mold to Windows, not the other way around, and Windows developers saw no need to change something that was working fine for them.  Microsoft usually doesn't support things that don't benefit Windows.

So a BIOS vendor could have added filesystem-loading support to the BIOS, but Windows likely wouldn't have bothered to use it, competing BIOS vendors might not implement it, and it'd have been pointless.

UEFI was an Intel-initiated thing with the Itanium, not a Microsoft-initiated thing.  Given that Intel makes most chipsets and motherboard hardware (and even motherboards), they were in a very good position to help make it the new standard.

Comment: UEFI isn't limited to Windows.  Might clarify to say be more OS independent

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS is specific to the motherboard and holds the lowest level settings, it starts the bootloader which is more abstracted than the BIOS from the hardware, the bootloader then starts the operating system, which holds the firmware. The BIOS doesn't load the OS because that simply isn't what it was made for, and using it as the bootloader would limit what OSes could be used based on the motherboard(If they chose to support Linux but not Solaris, Windows but nothing else, etc).